# Lock Sequences In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know of a resource that will tell me the sequence of locks that will be taken out on a table/page/row/index during a select/insert/update/delete in SQL Server 2005 AND how different table hints and isolation levels will impact the locks taken?

I know I am asking a lot here, but surely this information must be documented somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server locking is based on the concepts in [Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558601902). This book explains in great detail how locks are to be acquired, what locks are needed and *why* things must be the way they are.

The resources Marc linked are good coverage on the topic, but the details are scattered and you need to know where to look. Here is a primer to start you up:

The transaction isolation levels only affect read locks. Under normal `read committed` when reading a row an S-lock is acquired that is released immediately after the read. If the isolation level is elevated to `repeatable read` then the S-locks are held until the transaction ends. On higher `serializable` level [range locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191272.aspx) are placed instead of simple row locks, and they are held until the transaction commits. The snapshot modes are different in that they don't necessarily affect the type of lock, but the source of the read: rows are retrieved from the version store instead.

Lock order/hierarchy is always the same:

- an Sch-S lock is placed on the metadata at the start of any DML operation. DDL operations require Sch-M locks and thus conflict, so DML can be assured of the 'stability' of the schema on which it operates (object schema, not database schema...).
- The lock hierarchy path to a row is table-page-row. The actual granularity decided by the engine is [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189286.aspx). *Typically* is row.
- No matter the granularity, the path to the actual locked resource is protected with [intent locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx). Ie. to S-lock a row, the reader must acquire IS-lock on the table and the page. To S-lock a page, it needs an IS-lock on table.
- Single partition operations acquiring more that 5000 locks on a scan may trigger [lock escalation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx). Escalation is always an *attempt* (ie. will never block if failed). Escalation in practice goes always from row-level locking to table (partition in 2008) level locking.

The lock hints can never change the *order* of locks, they can only change:

- the type of lock (U-lock or X-lock when an S-lock would be required)
- the granularity (enforce table, or page or row)
- the duration (hold S-locks)
- the blocking behavior (readpast to skip incompatible rows).

I did not talk too much about insert/update/deletes since they are quite uninteresting: they require X locks, that's it. The only interesting thing about it is the way update works because it first acquire an U-lock that is later converted to an X-lock. This behavior is needed to leverage the [U-lock asymmetry](http://rusanu.com/2008/04/09/chained-updates/) that allows pending S-locks to drain before the update proceeds.

With this I hope you can go and find all the details left out from the articles and books linked.

Comment: Good answer! I just wonder if SQL engine will use a table lock if You do not specify a WHERE clause? Or the statistics have an impact on the locking mechanism, that is if sql engine finds out that your where clause will select a majority of the records?

Comment: No WHERE means a scan will be used. On read-committed means that each row will be locked and released, only one lock held at a time so there is no need to go for higher granularity. Under repeatable read or serializable there a table S-lock *may* be used. Same goes for statistics that predict a large return. Updates is a different story, they are much more likely to go for a higher granularity because X-locks are *always* retained for the duration of transaction.

Answer (score 2):

How about these:

- [Understanding Locking in SQL Server (2000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [Locking posts by Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Locking.aspx)
- [SQL Server Lock Types](http://etutorials.org/SQL/microsoft+sql+server+2000/Part+V+SQL+Server+Internals+and+Performance+Tuning/Chapter+38.+Locking+and+Performance/SQL+Server+Lock+Types/)
- [Locking results on SQLServerpedia.com](http://sqlserverpedia.com/search/?search=locking&x=0&y=0)

UPDATE: how about these more on transaction isolation levels and query hints:

- [SQL Server concepts: transaction isolation levels](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/07/25/3077.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2000 Unleashed](http://books.google.com/books?id=G2YqBS9CQ0AC&pg=RA1-PA1242&lpg=RA1-PA1242&dq=sql+isolation+levels+locks+query+hints&source=bl&ots=ZuRXEjIMeS&sig=fAfB-Yp1Kj_PDqNtSqjvzzEMb6M&hl=de&ei=5SmlSvjFKoGJ_Aag4tC-CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2#v=onepage&q=sql%20isolation%20levels%20locks%20query%20hints&f=false) on Google Books
- [Options affecting SQL Server locking behavior](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27020)

If you're interested in these rather advanced topics, I'd strongly recommend you get the [SQL Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243) book by Kalen Delaney (and others) which has all these nitty gritty details in them - even in this book, the "locking" topic only begin on pages 610 and up :-)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51rX6Z83U3L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51rX6Z83U3L._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Marc

Comment: No, doesn't quite have the information I'm looking for.

There is a lot of information about lock types and a little about the order of locks taken out in certain circumstances, but not really much about the order when using different table hints & isolation levels.

Comment: +1 lots of ood resources. I would just add Gray's black book, the one linked in my post

Comment: <hehe> better **ood** than **odd** :-)